# pickled fbprophet model won't run on heroku

Tags: python, heroku, facebook-prophet

I am unpickling the model like so:

```
filename = f"models/{model_name}"
model = pickle.load(open(filename, 'rb'))
forecast = model.make_future_dataframe(periods=int(period), freq='MS')
forecast = model.predict(forecast)
```

I get this error:

```
2022-04-28T00:12:11.900741+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/app.py", line 86, in create_figure_pred
2022-04-28T00:12:11.900742+00:00 app[web.1]: model = pickle.load(open(filename, 'rb'))
2022-04-28T00:12:11.900746+00:00 app[web.1]: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas._libs.arrays'
```

It's a Flask app.

I read that one potential solution for this error is to uninstall and reinstall pandas but pandas is installed by requirements.txt when I push.

Another possible solution is to import pandas._libs.arrays explicitly but this did not work.

```
2022-04-28T00:28:20.465322+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/app.py", line 13, in <module>
2022-04-28T00:28:20.465322+00:00 app[web.1]: import pandas._libs.arrays
2022-04-28T00:28:20.465326+00:00 app[web.1]: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 
'pandas._libs.arrays'
```

I found [an issue on github](https://github.com/facebook/prophet/issues/643) but this isn't very helpful because I don't have this problem when if I, for example, pickle and then unpickle in a notebook. It all works as expected.

fbprophet is definitely installed in the app. I can fit the model there but the page times out before it finishes. If it's a small dataset or forecasting period, it works.

There was another issue on github that no one responded to and sounded like a good question. I'll update here if I can find it again.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem.

```python
> python
Python 3.8.10 (default, Jun 22 2022, 20:18:18) 
[GCC 9.4.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pickle
>>> with open( 'myFile.pkl', 'rb' ) as f:
...     df = pickle.load( f )
... 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas._libs.arrays'
```

Looks like the pickled object was created with a version of pandas that does have ._libs.arrays, but the version attempting pickle.load does not :

```python
>>> pandas.__version__
'1.1.3'
>>> dir ( pandas._libs )
['Interval', 'NaT', 'NaTType', 'OutOfBoundsDatetime', 'Period', 'Timedelta', 'Timestamp', '__all__', '__builtins__', '__cached__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__', '__spec__', 'algos', 'groupby', 'hashing', 'hashtable', 'iNaT', 'index', 'indexing', 'internals', 'interval', 'join', 'json', 'lib', 'missing', 'ops', 'ops_dispatch', 'parsers', 'properties', 'reduction', 'reshape', 'sparse', 'testing', 'tslib', 'tslibs', 'window', 'writers']
```

Upgraded pandas :

```python
> python -m pip install pandas -U
Successfully installed pandas-1.4.3 python-dateutil-2.8.2 pytz-2022.2.1
```

Now it seems happy:

```
python
Python 3.8.10 (default, Jun 22 2022, 20:18:18) 
[GCC 9.4.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pickle
>>> with open( 'myFile.pkl', 'rb' ) as f:
...     df = pickle.load( f )
... 
>>> 
>>> import pandas
>>> 'arrays' in dir( pandas._libs )
True
```